# Unhandled promise rejection: Error: URL malformed, cannot be parsed

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoose

I am new to aws and mongodb at the same time, so I'm stuck at a very basic point in trying to connect to my mongo databse, hosted on an amazon linux ec2 instance. The reason is, I'm not able to build the path to my database.

Here is what I'm trying to use:

```
mongoose.connect('mongod://ec2-user@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27017/test' )
```

And here is the result of my test lambda function:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: URL malformed, cannot be parsed
```

I'm using mongodb 3.6.5.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Mongoose 5.x supports** following syntax for authorization and also make sure you have not used any special character in url like `@,-,+,>`

```
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, {
  auth: {
    user: MONGO_DB_USER,
    password: MONGO_DB_PASSWORD
  }
})
```

Or if you want to remove deprication warning **Avoid “current URL string parser is deprecated"**

Add option `useNewUrlParser`

```
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, {
  auth: {
    user: MONGO_DB_USER,
    password: MONGO_DB_PASSWORD
  },
  { useNewUrlParser: true }
})
```

Comment: For me, using Mongoose 5.6.11, it was simply a matter of removing special characters in the password string (i.e. a `+` and a `?`)

Comment: @samurai_jane Mongoose 5.6.11 supports both **connection string** as well as the above **option** syntax. But with the username and password having special characters the above syntax will be beneficial.

Answer (score 11):

My issue was a more simple URI issue. Since there was an `@` character in the mongod address.

I had to use this:

```
return mongoose.connect(encodeURI(process.env.DB_CONNECT)); //added ');'
```

Comment: Didn't work for me: getting `MongoParseError: Unescaped at-sign in authority section`

Comment: What is the output of the console.log of encodeURI(process.env.DB_CONNECT)?

Comment: Actually this did solve my problem eventually. Reason it didn't parse initially was that I had used a '@'-sign in my `db-user` name (mistaken for mLab account name). My apologies!

Comment: After trying this, I get ```MongoParseError: Invalid connection string```

Answer (score 2):

If you used the following URI in your environment file for example

`MongoDB://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds055915.mlab.com:55915/fullstack-vue-graphql`

Make sure your password in`MONGOD_URI` does not have a special character like `@`. I had used `@` as part of my password character and was getting the error. After I removed special characters from my `DB Password`, all worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the below worked fine.

Inside **db.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MONGODB_URI = "mongodb://host-name:27017/db-name?authSource=admin";
const MONGODB_USER = "mongouser";
const MONGODB_PASS = "myasri*$atIP38:nG*#o";

const authData =  {
    "user": MONGODB_USER,
    "pass": MONGODB_PASS,
    "useNewUrlParser": true,
    "useCreateIndex": true
}; 
mongoose.connect(
    MONGODB_URI, 
    authData,
    (err) => {
        if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB connection succeeded.'); }
        else { console.log('Error in MongoDB connection : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    }
);
```

Note:

My Node version is 10.x

MongoDb server version is 3.6.3

mongoose version is ^5.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I just want update the answer from @anthony-winzlet, because I have same error and I has solve with this code.

```
mongoose.connect(url, {
  auth: {
    user:'usrkoperasi',
    password:'password'
  },
  useNewUrlParser:true
}, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('connect!!!');
});
```

I just add callback and `useNewUrlParser:true`. I use `"mongoose": "^5.2.7",`.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed your app to Heroku make sure you updated the `Config Vars` as they are in your `.env` file. At least, this was my case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has accepted answer, but this is what worked for me:
I'm using Mongoose 6.0.5 and Mongodb 5.0.6, with authentication enabled and with special character (%) in the password:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', {
  auth: { username: "myusername", password: "mypassword%" },
  dbName: "mydbname",
  authSource: "mydbname",
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('mongoose error', err);
  }
});
```

Many solutions had only user and pass for auth that needed username and password instead. Also it needed dbName to get access to mydb's collections.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem but problem with password
should'nt special character

```
password not use like this  Admin@%+admin.com wrong


password use like this  Admin  right
```

or any password you wanna use