# Exporting mongoose connections to my model.js file

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I just migrated from Mongoose 3 to 5.1.5 and have some issues. I have a nodejs application running trying to connect to multiple DBs on different hosts.

Connection.js file : This is used to maintain the connections.

I am exporting my connections to my models and binding the schemas

**Connection.js** file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Mongoose = mongoose.Mongoose;
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

### -

-

```
const _connect = function (mongoUrl, options) {
    mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, options).then(
        () => { console.log('MongoDB Connected.'); },
        err => { console.log('MongoDB not Connected.'); }
        );
}
```

### -

```
module.exports = {
    conn1: new Connection('DB1'),
    conn2: new Connection('DB2')

};
```

In **model.js**

I have created different models and each is saved as a different file.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connections = require('./Connections');
```

### -

### -

```
 const schema = new mongoose.Schema(model);

 if (fileName.toLowerCase().includes('db2')) {
           connections.conn2.model(fileName, schema);
        } else {
           connections.conn1.model(fileName, schema);
        }
```

The whole setup was working properly in 3.x, but in 5.1.5, i get an issue 
"**connections.conn1.model is not a function**"

---

To test the whole scenario, I commented one connection and gave my exports as below in Connection.js:

```
module.exports = {
    mongoose: new Connection('DB1'),
};
```

and in model.js I just had

```
mongoose.model(fileName, schema);
```

which works perfectly. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I think you made a mistake in putting authenticaltions ... I got same error after updating and this will solve mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590080/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-url-malformed-cannot-be-parsed/50590439#50590439

Comment: Tried everything. Still the same :(