# mongoose.connect in my express app have name: MongoParserError , message: 'URI malformed, cannot be parsed'

Tags: mongoose, uri

```
mongoose
    .connect(db,{ useNewUrlParser: true}) 
    .then(() => console.log("MongoDB conected ..."))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

*Above mentioned is my code where 'db' is my database URI provided by mLab*

When I write run the express code its catches the error and gives out specific err message as:

> URI malformed, cannot be parsed

```
{ MongoError: URI malformed, cannot be parsed
    at parseConnectionString (/Users/dibs/Desktop/mern-ex/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/uri_parser.js:207:21)
    at connect (/Users/dibs/Desktop/mern-ex/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:179:3)
    at connectOp (/Users/dibs/Desktop/mern-ex/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:283:3)
    at executeOperation (/Users/dibs/Desktop/mern-ex/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:420:24)
    at MongoClient.connect (/Users/dibs/Desktop/mern-ex/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:168:10)
    at Promise (/Users/dibs/Desktop/mern-ex/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:487:12)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/dibs/Desktop/mern-ex/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:484:19)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/dibs/Desktop/mern-ex/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:229:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dibs/Desktop/mern-ex/server.js:20:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
  name: 'MongoParseError',
  message: 'URI malformed, cannot be parsed',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: Try with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590080/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-url-malformed-cannot-be-parsed/50590439#50590439

Comment: Try with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590080/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-url-malformed-cannot-be-parsed/63724737#63724737

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have some problem.
please check, that your uri isn't `undefined`
you can use `console.log(db)`

Comment: Exactly, my dotenv.config() was bellow my initialize(). In this case the env variable weren't being loaded.

Answer (score 7):

First check if the variable/env variable can be logged in the console

```
console.log(db);
```

If you are executing your application from some other file than your entry point, then add this in that other file

```
require('dotenv/config');
```

OR

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

OR

any such import(according to the package you are using) in connection file too.

Answer (score 5):

Hey I resolved this issue:

Try this, first insure you have **.env** file with the correct link, 
then go over to **index.js** and locate `require(“dotenv”).config()`

change the name from `dotenv` to `env` and the back to `dotenv` again.

what this does is it forces the MongoDb to restart, I tried using `Command + S` and it gave me the same err but after changing the values in **index.js** it works fine. [please refer to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECYLN.png)

Answer (score 4):

put something like this

```
mongoose.connect(DB_URL_WITHOUT_USER_PASS, {
auth: {
  user: "USER",
  password: "PASS"
},
useNewUrlParser:true
  }).then(
    () => { 
        console.log("Database connected");
    },
    err => { 
        /** handle initial connection error */ 
        console.log("Error in database connection. ", err);
    }
);
```

Comment: This worked for me, because my password had special characters.

Answer (score 0):

When developing with node.js, and hiding your URI in a .env file, it's easy to forget to include the "dotenv" module. If `console.log(YOUR_MONGO_URI)` is `undefined`, check your package.json file for the dotenv dependency. If it's not there,

```
npm install dotenv
```

and

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

in the relevant file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem doing the mongo university course for JavaScript devs.

I originally renamed dotenv_win to dotenv_win.env

I should have just renamed the whole thing to env

You can put this in the terminal to fix it:

```
ren dotenv_win .env
```