# Incomplete key value pair for option remote mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I'm trying to deploy my local node mongoDB app to Heroku. Everything is working fine on my local machine, no errors.

First thing I'm trying to do is to connect to a database on mlab. It seen very straight forward but I get this error:

```
err { MongoParseError: Incomplete key value pair for option
  name: 'MongoParseError',
  message: 'Incomplete key value pair for option',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

My code looks like this:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    const options = {
            useNewUrlParser: true
          };

    mongoose.connect("mongodb://username:password@xxxxx.mlab.com:39251/nameodDB",options).then(
   ()=>{
      console.log("connected to mongoDB")},
   (err)=>{
       console.log("err",err);
 });
```

Comment: what is your mongoose and mongodb version?

Comment: mongoose: ^5.2.3 (defined in package.json)

mongod version: 3.4.15 (MMAPv1) (on mlab)

Comment: Try with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590080/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-url-malformed-cannot-be-parsed/50590439#50590439

Comment: Thanks a million, that fixed it! Searched the entire internet and couldn't find it. made my day!

Comment: You are welcome man!!!

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB password needs to be URLEncoded if it consists of special characters like "@" which highlights the start of the host