# URL malformed, cannot be parsed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mlab, mern

Here is my error captured:

[image: captured]

and here are my coding files:

**server file**

[image: server file]

**keys file**

[image: keys file]

I just create connection to mlab using mongodb, node and reactjs. I'm using mongo db version 4.

need your help guys.

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Error: URL malformed, cannot be parsed
    at module.exports (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN08\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:17:21)
    at deprecated (internal/util.js:47:15)
    at connect (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN08\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:179:3)
    at connectOp (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN08\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\mongo_client_ops.js:283:3)
    at executeOperation (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN08\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:420:24)
    at MongoClient.connect (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN08\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:168:10)
    at Promise (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN08\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:493:12)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN08\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:490:19)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN08\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:230:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MERNapps\TestMERN08\server.js:12:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
(node:3696) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
server running on port 5000
```

Comment: I think the issue is with your keys file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: URL malformed, cannot be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590080/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-url-malformed-cannot-be-parsed)

Comment: Some tips for you: Never share your keys publically [mongos url]

Comment: Never share your keys publically [mongos url] -- oops.. and thank you for that tip buddy.. actually it's a test account. anyway it's not good know ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your keys. Try using:

```
module.exports= {
  mongoURI : "your-uri-string",
  options:{key:value}
}
```

And use the keys as:

```
mongoose.connect(db.mongoURI,options);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. am going to change my code now as above.

Answer (score 1):

a very common error with MongoDB atlas. better still follow this procedure

1. Install Mongo DB compass
2. use Default setting

> hostname: localhost & port 27017

3. create a database with the project name and then collection: user
4. Connect with the code below on entry js. route

> mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/projectname')
>       .then(() => console.log('mongo db working'))
>       .catch(err => console.log('ERROR is', err))