# Unhandled Promise Rejection Error (async function without a catch block)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

I looked through other questions on this topic, but couldn't find a fix for this issue.  I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpJO0T08Bnc) on building a todo application with the MERN stack (I'm stuck around minute 16:00).

When I try to start my server, I'm getting a deprecation warning saying "current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect", and an unhandled promise rejection - "This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()".

I've tried adding a catch block to my code, but I still receive the error.  Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga')

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
 text: String,
 complete: Boolean
});


const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    hello(name: String): String!
  }
  type Todo {
   id: ID
   text: String!
   complete: Boolean!
  }
  type Mutation {
   createTodo(text: String!): Todo
  }
`
;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: (_, { name }) => `Hello ${name || "World"}`,
  },
  Mutation: {
   createTodo: async (_, { text }) => {
    const todo = new Todo({ text, complete: false });
    await todo.save();
    return todo;
   }
  }
};

const server = new GraphQLServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
  server.start(() => console.log('Server is running on localhost:4000'));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });`?

Comment: @Tholle Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it, but it said "port must be specified" and I still got the previous error message as well.

Comment: whats the mongodb version you are using? 
May be you need to delete the latest version of mongodb and install the past version i.e. 3.0.x which support such kind of behavour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: URL malformed, cannot be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590080/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-url-malformed-cannot-be-parsed)

Comment: @VishnuShekhawat I just installed it Saturday and ran an update yesterday, so I believe I'm using 4.0.  I'll try your suggestion.  Thanks!