# Mongodb auth url from .env file of node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

From this document [secure mongodb](https://do.co/2JCbRTI) i want to secure my mongodb with authentication.
Actually in .env file of node.js app i connect to mongodb with following url :

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://username:password@my_ip_address:4000/myDb", 
function (err) {
   if (err) console.error('Could not connect to mongodb.');
});
```

Where username/password are my ssh credentials. My question is how i can connect to my secure mongodb ? connecting from Studio 3T is working well but from my nodejs app, i cannot connect to mongodb.

Anyone could help me please ?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No error when querying from node.js when i do myDb.find(req.body) nothing happens, when i disable auth from mongodb /etc/mongodb.config i am able to query

Comment: Could you show your query... Run `myDb.count()` and check the result

Comment: Hi, myDb.count() shows nothing, console.log("test") above is showing but not the query

Comment: You should post some code otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i just figured out that in my password i have an '@' and i should encode it : mongodb://username:password@my_ip:my_port/myDb, {url_decode_auth:true}, callback), where @ inside password is endoded with %40
And it works well.

Comment: If your password contains special character then you should go this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590080/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-url-malformed-cannot-be-parsed/50590439#50590439

Comment: yes, you're right thanks again