# (node:32032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: Authentication failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cloud9

I'm trying to connect mongodb from mlabs. I've inserted the following code:

```
Mongoose.connect('mongodb://<dhan004>:<password1>@ds163402.mlab.com:63402/projecttwist', {useNewUrlParser: true });
```

It then gave me this error:

```
(node:32032) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: Authentication failed.
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: The error indicates that it failed on authentication, so check the username and password portion of your connection string, which usually goes by: `protocol://username:password@host:port/path`, in this case protocol is `mongodb`, `host:port` parts you should double check too, and `path` part in this case point to the DB. Double check all parts based on this and try again.

Comment: appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: URL malformed, cannot be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590080/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-url-malformed-cannot-be-parsed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the brackets(both < and the >) from the username and password section.

For username should use: **dhan004**

And for the password you should use: **password1**

So your final db address should be:

```
Mongoose.connect('mongodb://dhan004:password1@ds163402.mlab.com:63402/projecttwist', {useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Comment: Glad to help you. will you please add the accepted flag to the answer.