# connecting mongoose to mongoDB atlas and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my mongoose connection code:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://Sarthak:*******:Wb@cluster0-jli2a.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true",{ useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(()=>{
        console.log("Connected to mongo database");
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log("Error connecting mongo database",err);
    });
```

I got the errors below, any idea how to fix this?

> Error connecting mongo database { MongoParseError: Unescaped colon in authority section
>   at parseConnectionString (/home/sarthak/Projects/thePracticalGuide/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/uri_parser.js:250:23)
>   at QueryReqWrap.dns.resolveTxt [as callback] (/home/sarthak/Projects/thePracticalGuide/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/uri_parser.js:126:7)
>   at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:240:10)
>   name: 'MongoParseError',
>   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

[image: This is the error I am getting while connection]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: URL malformed, cannot be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590080/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-url-malformed-cannot-be-parsed)

Comment: Please insert the commands/logs as text, not as image. There's myriad of reasons why (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3995261)

Comment: did any solution work?

Comment: No @amitavamozumder , I switched to mlab instead, have developed around 4-5 personal projects till now. It is working awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to use this way of connection too**

```
 /* I've removed the ":Wb" between your password and @clus... As mongoDB atlas website didn't use that in my generated connection string */
  mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://Sarthak:*******@cluster0-jli2a.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true",{ useNewUrlParser: true });    

  mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(`Mongoose connection error: ${err}`);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

**Otherwise things to consider:**

- Make sure that you've added your connecting device IP address in the IP whitelist in the security tap of your cluster in mongoDB atlas website (if you've already done that you might try giving permission to every IPs by adding 0.0.0.0/0 to check there's no issue regarding to this)
- Regarding to the password, you may got confused with the mongoDB atlas login password, than the user you made for the cluster (this is a common mistake that mongoDB atlas newbies make).
- If not and you're using the right password, you can try to delete the user and re-create it again in the security tab (in the clusters view in mongoDB atlas website). First consider giving the user a very basic password without any special character and try connecting again to ensure that it's not an encoding issue.
- At the end if none of above worked with you try making connection via shell. (you can see the connection string in the mongoDB atlas website, in the connect section of your cluster. There you can get better logs regarding to the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just go to atlas website security tab and edit the password of the user and make sure you do not use "@" or ":". That's it.

Comment: Consider adding a source to the information you are suggesting and explain why it's relevant to what was provided in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode your password in the connection string:

```
const connectionString = `mongodb://yourUsername:${encodeURIComponent('yourPassword')}@127.0.0.1:27017/mydb`;
```

Comment: Since I consume a password in JS and generate it in Go, I use https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#QueryEscape

Answer (score 1):

The error description is pretty clear - do you have a colon in your password? The typical connectionstring format is "mongodb+srv:[username:password@]host1..." so an unescaped colon would throw a parse error.

Comment: No, there is only a underscore in my password.

Comment: two suggestions1) anything ahead of the '@' is your password - remove ':Wb' 2) specify the db name in the options. eg. mongoose.connect('"mongodb+srv://Sarthak:*******@cluster0-jli2a.mongodb.net/',{dbName: 'test'})

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, also with "unescaped colons" even though they were very clearly escaped. Try this:

```
var uri = encodeURI('mongodb+srv://Sarthak:*******:Wb@cluster0-jli2a.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting **"Unescaped colon in authority section"**  using MongoDB Compass when entering the connection string.

For which -

I went into **"Create Free Cluster"** button and made a cluster.

Then I got the connection string. However, while entering the available connection string I got the error.

I just changed the password by logging into mongodb atlas.

Here is the procedure I used -->

```
 [1]  To change the password - click on encode URI
```

[image]

```
 [2]   It will take you here -->
```

[image]

```
  [3]   Click on the edit button from the screen above and change your password.
```

[image]

I followed the above steps and was able to login.