# Mongodb Atlas: Error: Username contains an illegal unexpected character

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, connection-string

I have created an online account account with MongoDB Atlas. And now I am trying to  connect to it. Form the Atlas admin panel, I can retrieve the connection string for my node app.I click at connect and it brings me a modal form where I select "Connect you Application". I select it and then copy the whole connection string proposed.

[image]

After that, I apply the connection in my application and I replace on the password placeholder, my real password.(something like:)

```
await mongoose.connect("mongo://_myusername_:_password__")@cluster0-shard--00-00-neswb.mongodb.net:27017...
```

But I get the below error:

[image]

I cannot understand what is the illegal character here. This is a connection string generated by Mongodb Atlas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been on this issues from quite some time now.

Thank you!

Comment: May be this will work https://stackoverflow.com/a/50590439/7510657. Documented [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options)

Comment: I just tried the above suggestion. But now I am getting a:
"Error: connection 0 to _url_ closed

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by added the {useNewUrlParser: true} to my collection payload