# Error Message with MongoDB and Mongoose connection URL malformed, cannot be parsed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

I am following a tutorial on creating a Fullstack project Using MongoDB as my database. The tutorial is a bit outdated as it seems MongoDB has updated their process renaming the apps to clusters from what I can see. I tried connecting MongoDB to my server and received URL malformed, cannot be parsed as an error.

EDIT: I removed the images of the code

My server file:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });

mongoose
   .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
   .then(() => console.log("DB connected"))
   .catch(err => console.error(err));


const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT  || 4444;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

My variable.env file:

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://Ernest:<password>@cluster0-ltxeh.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Error Message:

```
Error: URL malformed, cannot be parsed
    at module.exports (/Users/eboolo/Desktop/react-recipes/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:17:21)
    at connect (/Users/eboolo/Desktop/react-recipes/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:880:3)
    at connectOp (/Users/eboolo/Desktop/react-recipes/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:269:3)
    at executeOperation (/Users/eboolo/Desktop/react-recipes/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:420:24)
    at MongoClient.connect (/Users/eboolo/Desktop/react-recipes/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:260:10)
    at /Users/eboolo/Desktop/react-recipes/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:427:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/eboolo/Desktop/react-recipes/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:424:19)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/eboolo/Desktop/react-recipes/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:208:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eboolo/Desktop/react-recipes/server.js:6:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Comment: [This may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590080/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-url-malformed-cannot-be-parsed)

Comment: Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. [Learn more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)